# Local variable vs static variable memory and performance

Tags: c#, performance, static-members

Where are static variables stored inside a non static method call? I.e. Inside `CalculateTotalStatic()`, we are incrementing the static member `MyStaticVariableHolder.Total` and are also comparing the variable `i` with `MyStaticVariableHolder.TotalArray.Length` within the for loop.

On the other hand, in another version of this method `CalculateTotalLocal()`,  we are using local variables declared within the method to perform both the above actions.

During `CalculateTotalLocal`, there will be two additional variables placed on the stack which will hold their values on the stack itself (`localTotal` and `localLength`). What happens in the case of `CalculateTotalStatic`? Does it access the static variables from the heap every time? Also, `CalculateTotalLocal` is 10% faster than `CalculateTotalStatic`. What is the correct reason for this performance improvement?

EDIT - I guess I'm not being very clear - apologies for that.

What I'm trying to say is:

**can (according to C# spec) static variable access be optimized the same way as local variable by compliant C# compiler/JIT?**

```
 class MyStaticVariableHolder
{
    public static int[] TotalArray = new int[100];
    public static int Total = 1;
}
class Trial
{
    public void CalculateTotalStatic()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MyStaticVariableHolder.TotalArray.Length; i++)
        {
            MyStaticVariableHolder.Total += i;
        }

    }

    public void CalculateTotalLocal()
    {
        int localTotal = MyStaticVariableHolder.Total;
        int[] localTotalArray = MyStaticVariableHolder.TotalArray;
        int localLength = MyStaticVariableHolder.TotalArray.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < localLength; i++)
        {
            localTotal += i;
        }
        MyStaticVariableHolder.Total = localTotal;

    }

}
```

I was also looking at this link - http://www.dotnetperls.com/local-variable-field-optimization for reference but I didnt achieve as much performance improvement as they were getting.

Comment: Be careful with `+=` and static variables, if more than one thread does it at the same time you could get incorrect results.

Comment: Before asking for performance help, you might want to read [Which is faster](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert. I'd especially focus here on #4.

Comment: Your loops seem pretty nonsensical to me. Do you mean to be adding `TotalArray[i]` instead of just `i`? Your current loops are just adding the indexer. 0 + 1 + 2 ... length-1. And if that's what you want to do, the methods could just be replaced with `Enumerable.Range(0, length).Sum()`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks I've read that before - The purpose of this post was theoretical - what makes one method faster than the other, rather than, "I need to make this as fast as possible"

Comment: @itsme86 yes I could, but I'm interested in knowing what the difference is when calling a method that accesses multiple static variables within a method vs storing those static variables in local variables and then calling those local variables instead of the static ones. Difference in memory, performance etc.

Comment: I feel like your question doesn't pertain to C# as much as it does to the specific jitter you're using. It seems like it could change between environments or even between versions. I could be wrong.

Comment: @itsme86 whats your opinion in the link I posted?

Comment: The best advice I can give, as always, is **don't** true to learn "rules" for performance. Write *simple*, straightforward code that performs the correct action. Then *measure* the performance (of the system as a whole), and compare it with the performance *requirements* that you set (you did remember to set these?). Only if the performance doesn't meet your requirements should you be making comparisons, and you should be focussing on the bottlenecks.

Comment: I think if you rephrase your question as "can (according to C# spec) static variable access be optimized the same way as local variable by compliant C# compiler/JIT" would be more specific/answerable. As of now question is mostly comparing versions of JIT as @itsme86 pointed out.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov got it thanks - just edited

Comment: Unlike in the Local method, in the Static method the compiler/jitter cannot be sure the length of the array won't change during the loop. So it has to ask the array for it each time. This will typically be a little slower that just accessing a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the boilerplate MSDN annotation about the thread-safety of a framework class:

> #### Thread Safety
>
> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Which in general is a load of horse-feathers and should not be assumed to be accurate, it is copy/paste documentation.  There is however one guarantee you get for static variables, and the only reason this blurb is included, the .NET memory model *does* promise that assignments to such a variable can be visible to other threads.

This means that the jitter cannot optimize a read or write from such a variable.  The underlying load or store instruction cannot be delayed and cannot be reordered.  This does not come for free.

No such issue with a local variable, the jitter has a hard guarantee that this variable can never be visible to another thread.  This permits the jitter to *enregister* the variable, storing it in a CPU register.  The fastest kind of memory available on a processor.

Do keep in mind that the mental model is not correct, "there will be two additional variables placed on the stack" is not accurate.  Both variables will in fact be stored in a CPU register when you run the Release build of your program without a debugger attached.  The perf improvement you get is measurable in a test like this.

Storage for the static variable is normally allocated from the loader heap, an AppDomain implementation detail.  This does not otherwise affect perf of the program, the jitter knows the exact address of the variable since it is the one that allocated the storage.

Comment: Thank you! One clarification - ` Both variables will in fact be stored in a CPU register when you run the Release build of your program without a debugger attached`. This is true for reference types as well? Custom types?

Comment: Yes.  But of course only the reference, the object is stored on the GC heap.  And is thus not thread-safe.

Answer (score 5):

> Where are static variables stored inside a non static method call?

I take it you mean: a value is fetched from a static variable in order to perform some computation on it. Therefore a copy is made of the value. To what storage is the copy made?

At the level of IL, it's made to the evaluation stack.  The runtime has broad latitude to reify the evaluation stack however it likes.  The stack of the current thread, or registers are both likely.

I note that the copy can be made to a heap location in some scenarios.

> What happens in the case of CalculateTotalStatic? Does it access the static variables from the heap every time?

Wait, who said they were on the heap in the first place? There's no requirement that static variables be stored on the garbage collected heap. Their memory is not going to be collected, so why should they be on the heap?  (The array that the variable refers to is on the heap of course.)

Let's rephrase.

> What happens in the case of CalculateTotalStatic? Does it do a fresh access to the static variable every time?

The question still isn't answerable. Rephrase again.

> Is the runtime *required* to do a fresh fetch from the variable every time?

No.  The runtime is permitted to do **any optimization whatsoever that would be invisible in a single-threaded program**.  (This is a slight over-statement; there are some optimizations it will not perform. I'm not going to list what they are.) Internalize that fact.  In a single threaded program everything is stable unless made to move.  In a multithreaded program, everything is moving unless made to stay still. The runtime is permitted to assume the former even in a world where the latter is true.

> Also, CalculateTotalLocal is 10% faster than CalculateTotalStatic. What is the correct reason for this performance improvement?

I have no idea. Examine the generated code and see what the difference is.

> can (according to C# spec) static variable access be optimized the same way as local variable by compliant C# compiler/JIT?

Absolutely yes. That falls squarely under the "any optimization that would be invisible in a single-threaded program".

Moreover: the runtime is not just permitted to reorder reads and writes as it sees fit. It is also permitted to allow *different threads to observe an inconsistent world*. If one thread observes a particular time sequence of variables being read and written, another thread is permitted to observe a completely different interleaving of the reads and writes.

Moreover: do not ever forget that by *the runtime* I mean also anything the runtime depends upon like, say, *the CPU*.  Remember, CPUs are permitted broad latitude to reorder reads and writes as they see fit. Just because you are looking at some x86 code that plainly reads a location out of memory into a register, that has **absolutely nothing whatsoever** to do with the time at which the read actually goes to memory. That memory location might already be in the cache, and main memory might already have been written on another thread, effectively moving the read backwards in time.

Moreover: volatile does not necessarily help. For people who believe they can correct predict the behaviour of a program that has only volatile accesses to static variables on a *strong* memory model, I encourage you to read http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/ and see if you can correctly deduce the permitted sequences of reads and writes. Remember, this is on a *strong* memory model; now think about how much harder things might get on weak memory models!

You are in deep waters the moment you abandon standard patterns and practices for sharing memory across threads. Don't go there.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your `static` fields are declared as `volatile`, the .NET JIT is free to do the same optimization you did, and it's becoming better at this with each major version, which would explain the difference from the somehow dated "Dot Net Perls" article.

My best guess at the static version 10% difference would be the `static int[] TotalArray = new int[100]` initializer, which can and most probably *does* impose some overhead on the `MyStaticVariableHolder static` member access to ensure it's run only once and only once before it's actually needed.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What does initializing have to do with the two method calls?

Comment: To have an initialized static field, the .NET runtime needs to ensure the initializer is run sometimes before the field is accessed but exactly once. As is JITted and allows dynamic type/assembly loading, it cannot do everything on "link/load time", resulting in the JIT generating some check-and-run code on MyStaticVariableHolder field access.

Comment: I see, so switching the order of the method calls should reverse the performance? Or bring them more to par?

Comment: It depends on the JIT how much it needs to compile, it may easily end up generating the pre-initialization checks in both methods - the only way to avoid them for sure is to have non-initialized static fields and no static constructor.

Comment: Hmm reversing the order changed nothing.